# Mathlive, reach and convertLatexToMathMl

Tags: reactjs, math, editor

I installed mathlive (npm i mathlive) to my react project.
It shows my mathinput field, but I get some failures:

Failed to decode downloaded font:

OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008813135 mathlive.mjs:23143

MathLive 0.98.6: The math fonts could not be loaded from "http://localhost:3000/static/js/fonts" {cause: DOMException: A network error occurred.}

I know I can use import "//unpkg.com/mathlive" but then I cant use latexToMathML.

Any suggestion what Im doing wrong?

```
import "mathlive";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const mf = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(`\\frac{1}{2} \\sqrt{16}`);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <math-field ref={mf} onInput={(evt) => setValue(evt.target.value)}>
        {value}
      </math-field>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Searched the web for solutions and looked through the main code.